# Type arguments cannot be inferred from usage, Can anyone help please?

Tags: c#, linq, compiler-errors, linq-to-objects, dynamic-linq

I am trying to use Dynamic Linq (the one published by ScottGu) to do a GroupBy (lambda expression). I have an object. And i am doing AsQueryable. THis is what i have..

```
var result = Items.AsQueryable().GroupBy("DeliveryDate");
```

but it gives me an error saying that arguments cannot be inferred from usage. I think its not looking at the right OrderBy.

Items is a `List<Stock>`.

I tried adding the < > to `GroupBy` but i think i need to pass more than 1 item. I am a little confused.

The field that i am passing in (via a string) could be any type, in this example it is a DateTime.

If I do my standard LINQ it does work. i.e.:

```
var result = Items.AsQueryable().GroupBy( x => x.DeliveryDate);
```

Here is the extension method (from ScottGu):

```
public static IQueryable GroupBy(this IQueryable source, string keySelector, string elementSelector, params object[] values) {
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (keySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("keySelector");
    if (elementSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("elementSelector");
    LambdaExpression keyLambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(source.ElementType, null, keySelector, values);
    LambdaExpression elementLambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(source.ElementType, null, elementSelector, values);
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery(
        Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), "GroupBy",
            new Type[] { source.ElementType, keyLambda.Body.Type, elementLambda.Body.Type },
            source.Expression, Expression.Quote(keyLambda), Expression.Quote(elementLambda)));
}
```

I have the using in the project `using System.Linq.Dynamic;` - and i am using dynamic `OrderBy` in another method, so i know it should be able to see it.

I am a little confused, it seems using dynamic LINQ it doesn't understand what object I am using.

Comment: See also [my article on CP](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/HandleGridViewOnSorting.aspx) for another but similar solution of the same problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extension method with this signature

```
public static IQueryable GroupBy(this IQueryable source, 
        string keySelector, string elementSelector, params object[] values)
```

isn't being invoked by this line

```
var result =  Items.AsQueryable().GroupBy("DeliveryDate");
```

as there's only **one** non-`this` argument! So the compiler thinks you're after the regular `GroupBy` (that takes a `Func`) and gets confused.

You need to supply the other `selector` string.

*edit* to add

The normal `GroupBy` has [lots of overloads](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/01/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-21-groupby.aspx), and so Dynamic Linq needs to offer just as much flexibility. `GroupBy` produces a sequence of groupings each of which has a **key** and a sequence of **elements**. If, as in your conventional LINQ call, no mention is made of the elements, the source objects themselves are used as elements.

For example, using some hypothetical classes, grouping `Orders` by `OrderDate` produces an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, Order>>`.

But we could say that we only care about the `OrderId` in the output, so we could give `GroupBy` an `elementSelector` to make it produce an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, int>>`.

To tell Dynamic Linq to use the `Item` itself as the element, we use the magic string `"it"` as the `elementSelector`:

```
var result = Items.AsQueryable().GroupBy("DeliveryDate", "it");
```

This should then have the same effect as the conventional LINQ call

```
var result = Items.AsQueryable().GroupBy(i => i.DeliveryDate);
```

Comment: Thanks! yes it appears to be working! A big thank you. So what do i need to pass actually with the 2 strings? What is keyselector and element selector actually?   Key select = DeliveryDate ?? what is element selector?

Comment: @abatishchev Same reason as Entity Framework ended up using it - it's a nice short way to refer to 'the current unnamed parameter'. It's [mentioned in the docs for Dynamic Linq under "current instance"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720664/what-is-it-in-entity-framework/6720854#6720854)

Comment: @AakashM: So seems that's hardcoded value for `Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "it");`, isn't it?

Comment: @abatishchev basically, yes, although there's special-casing to map `"it"` to the single unnamed parameter when that's what there is.